# How to get a list from dict with lambda/maps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have this dict, 
where I manage a list of programs and their different versions

```
data = {
  'soft1':{
     'v1':{...},
     'v2':{...}
   },
  'soft2':{
     'v1':{...},
     'v2':{...}
  },
  'soft3':{
     'v1':{...}
  },
  ...
}
```

now I need a list like to:

```
list_=[
    'soft1 v1',
    'soft1 v2',
    'soft2 v1',
    'soft2 v2',
    'soft3 v1' 
]
```

with list comprehension

```
list_ = [soft + " " + ver for soft in data.keys() for ver in data[soft].keys()]
```

***but I would like a more efficient method and more pythonic***,

I try:

```
list_ = [map(lambda soft: map(lambda ver: [soft + " " + ver], data[soft].keys()), data.keys())]
```

but it generates this error

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "map") to str

*I appreciate opinions and corrections*

Comment: The list comprehension is the most pythonic approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension with f-strings (available in Python 3.6+):

```
res = [f'{k} {w}' for k, v in data.items() for w in v]

['soft1 v1', 'soft1 v2', 'soft2 v1', 'soft2 v2', 'soft3 v1']
```

For earlier versions of Python you can use `str.format`:

```
res = ['{0} {1}'.format(k, w) for k, v in data.items() for w in v]
```

This will be more efficient as:

- Formatted string literals are more efficient than other methods of string concatenation.
- Extracting key-value pairs via `dict.items` is more efficient than iterating keys and accessing values separately.
- `map` + `lambda` with non built-in functions are less efficient than list comprehensions.

Comment: thansk, your opinion allowed me a more readable and flexible code.

Comment: @4l3x, No problem, if this helped consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left).